# .mdb cannot link in netbean

Tags: java, ms-access, netbeans

I want to ask. I'm now current doing on an assignment  to do an atm machine interface but it seems I cannot link the Access file to Netbean. this is the snippet

```
try{
  Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
  con = DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:ATMINFO");
  }
catch(Exception ex){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failed Connection","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }
```

need help.

Comment: I always got the error message

Comment: the system has a login button, but when I click on it, it pops-up the error message, even when logging in it shows error message. I already put some accounts in the access file but it seems it cannot link.

Comment: What does `System.getProperty("java.version")` return?